# Getting an error for React Native while Building Android App

Tags: react-native

I am getting following error while building Android Application. Can anyone explain why it is happening

```
    import type {CommandT} from './commands';
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Module._compile (E:\React_Project\OneTap\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (E:\React_Project\OneTap\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! OneTap@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the OneTap@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19654) it looks like this is a problem related to RN 0.56 in Windows. As a workaround I would recommend using version 0.55.4.

Comment: I did that I build React project with **react-native init {proj_name} --version react-native@0.55.4** the project created when I run  **npm start** it giving me same error

Comment: Ok I got why I am facing issue because when I build project using **react-native init {proj_name} --version react-native@0.55.4** the I used to fire **npm audit** and **npm audit fix** to close vulnerabilities that cause me throw same error mention above. Without fix I am able to build project. **Thanks !!**